# AttributeError: 'NoneType' discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**code**

```py
global Vc
    global Tune
    try:
        Vc = await stage.connect()
        member = guild.get_member(config["bot_id"])
        await member.edit(suppress=False)
    except CommandInvokeError:
        pass
    while True:
        while Vc.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        else:
            Tune = get_info.write_song()
            Vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"songs/{Tune}"))
            audiofile = eyed3.load(f"songs/{Tune}")
            title = audiofile.tag.title
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{title}"))
            Vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(Vc.source, volume=config["volume"])
            if "suppress=False" in str(stage.voice_states):
                pass
            else:
                await member.edit(suppress=False)
```

**error**

> File "main.py", line 84, in on_ready
> await member.edit(suppress=False) AttributeError: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'edit'

I've already enabled the **Privileged Gateway Intents** and I don't know why I still have this error reason...

Comment: You use `guild.get_member(config["bot_id"])` to get a member which represents your bot?

Comment: now the error reason is TypeError: 'Member' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Use `guild.me` instead of `guild.get_member(config["bot_id"])`. It's much better. Also you can check `if member is not None:` before edit.